# Tp_smapi on Thinkpad T440

Tags: 14.04, kernel, thinkpad, tp-smapi

I have a Thinkpad T440 with Ubuntu 14.04 (using i3wm).  I have had trouble installing tp_smapi.  I successfully installed it with dpkg -- can't remember whether I used apt or just downloaded it somewhere -- but I can't load the module.

When I use modprobe on tp_smapi, I get this:

"modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'tp_smapi': No such device or address"

Note that this is different from the error I get when I mistype the module name.

I read somewhere that I might have to rebuild my kernel for it to work, but I'd thought that the kernel I was using (3.13.0-24) had that already set up.

Has anyone gotten it to work?  I hate how Lenovo manages the batteries!

Comment: I have a Thinkpad T440s also with the new Haswell processor, and I get the same error. So tp_smapi probably doesn't work on them.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Tp_smapi#Installation_on_Ubuntu it says tp_smapi can not work on T430 because of the Ivy Bridge cpus.

Comment: I have a T440, with a Haswell processor; does the same go for that?